# After uploading an Excel file to SharePoint, When i open it online the year jumps from 2020 to 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I have an issue with an uploaded excel file, when opening it online I get incorrect dates (the year changes from 2020 to 2016). But if I open it on my desktop it shows correctly.

What may be the cause of this alteration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the regional settings in the Site Collection settings in SharePoint.  SharePoint online normally defaults to whatever timezone the server is in unless you change the regional settings for the site collection.  For me, that means Pacific Time, even though my local time zone is Eastern US.  Also, the Z you see at the end of the time string in Flow says that time is being shown in UTC.  So if you input that into a SharePoint list it will display in SharePoint as 8 hours earlier (PST is -8 from UTC). I suspect that you are seeing something similar.

Best,
Jerry.